# keras - 1D-CNN input compatibility error, a time series problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I am using the below code where I am trying to train a 1d CNN, my x_train data shape is (10027, 5, 14) and y_train shape is (10027,4). But I am getting an error (below the code)
regarding the shape compatibility.

````
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="valid",
                        input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features))
  
])
model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

 verbose, epochs, batch_size = 0, 10, 5 



 model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)```

Below error 

```ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:755 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:203 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:152 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:256 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py:1537 categorical_crossentropy
        return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py:4833 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 1, 20) are incompatible```
````

Answer (score 0):

I mean, the last layer of your network is a conv1D with filters=20, so the output of your network will be (batch, 1, 20), and you give a Y with a shape of (batch, 4).

The loss don't understand what it has to compare, since the two arrays are not matching at all.

If you want to have something working you should give a last layer compatible with your Y :

```py
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="valid",
                        input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_features)),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation = 'softmax')  
])
```